# USE RIGHT with CHARINDEX using string with multiple characters fails

Tags: sql-server, string, replace, right-to-left, charindex

I have a a text filed which I need to get just a part of the string from the left.

```
select top 100 Description, right(Description, 
charindex('</span>', reverse(Description))-1) 
as CleanedDesc 
from MyDB.dbo.MyTable_output
```

when rung the query if tails with the following error:

Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

This is actually correct as I specified `charindex('</span>'`

which is not right, it has to be a single character, but unfortunately but text value "separator is exactly  .

Below is the sample of string data which you can use for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">  <html>  <head>  <title></title>  </head>  <body>  <span class="added">Added: <input type="hidden" name="dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][description][0][added_on]" value="2017-06-19 10:32:17">Jun 19, 2017 10:32 am</span> This solicitation will contain NSN 1d2323, OIL. A Request for Proposal (RFP) will be issued for award .....ed item and must be acquired from an approved manufacturer. The approved sources are:<br>  SEYER INDUSTRIES, INC. 19494 P/N 74A150625-1006<br>
```

Comment: It fails because you're looking for the /span tag but you are reversing the Description string.  You will not find that in the reversed string.  Why are you reversing the string?  What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found workaround. That is to replace '' using CTE with a character that I make sure is not present in the Description column. I scanned my table using this code

```
 select * from  MyDB.dbo.MyTable_output where Description like '%~%'.
```

But I do have some records that do have this values "~". So it's not an option.

But even if I would not found any that does not seem to be practical solution in the long run

```
;with cte as (
select top 100 RowNo, replace(Description, '</span>','~') as ReplacedDesc from InputTemp.dbo.SearchFBO_output 
) 
select 
RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EntityPKID),
Project,
[Title],

RIGHT(cte.ReplacedDesc, charindex('~', reverse(cte.ReplacedDesc))-1) as Description,

FROM
 MyDB.dbo.MyTable_output o
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.RowNo = o.RowNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can play with the delimiters.

If open to a Table-Valued Function, consider the following:

Tired of extracting data ... left, right, charindex, reverse, ... I modified a parse function to accept two non like delimiters (up to 100 characters not one).

**Example [or dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=688d649b393997cebb75ee219cbe7617)**

```
Declare @YourTable table ([ID] int,[Description] varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">  <html>  <head>  <title></title>  </head>  <body>  <span class="added">Added: <input type="hidden" name="dnf_class_values[procurement_notice][description][0][added_on]" value="2017-06-19 10:32:17">Jun 19, 2017 10:32 am</span> This solicitation will contain NSN 1d2323, OIL. A Request for Proposal (RFP) will be issued for award .....ed item and must be acquired from an approved manufacturer. The approved sources are:<br>  SEYER INDUSTRIES, INC. 19494 P/N 74A150625-1006<br>')


Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract]([Description],'>','</span') B
 Where RetVal>''
```

**Returns**

```
ID  RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1   1       262     Jun 19, 2017 10:32 am
```

**Now,** if the delimeters were **>** and **<**, the following would be returned

```
ID  RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1   7   136 Added: 
1   8   262 Jun 19, 2017 10:32 am
1   9   290  This solicitation will contain NSN 1d2323, OIL. A Request for Proposal (RFP) will be issued for award .....ed item and must be acquired from an approved manufacturer. The approved sources are:
1   10  487   SEYER INDUSTRIES, INC. 19494 P/N 74A150625-1006
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1 

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - Regarding Comment**

You may notice I added a silly ending delimiter of `|||`

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract]([Description]+'|||','</span>','|||') B
 Where RetVal>''
```

Comment: Hi John, I just need to return simply need to return everything that follows after my so called delimiter "</span>"

Comment: @enigma6205 this approach may be a little overkill for your request.  Just keep it in your back pocket, perhaps one day it may help